# WCF. Leave an empty namespace in the SoapAction

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I've got a requirement to modify the soapAction in my WSDL to contain only ServiceOperation/ServiceMethod inside.

When I leave the namespace property empty it sets it to:

```
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:ServiceName/GetCustomers" style="document"/>
```

When I remove the namespace property, then the tempuri.org namespace steps in and spoils the result.

What has to be done:

```
<soap:operation soapAction="ServiceName/GetCustomers" style="document"/>
```

Is there any way to achieve this? 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that it can be done by specifying the action directly on the method:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "ServiceName/GetCustomers")]
```